# How to check a checkbox within a indexed_property

Tags: watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have a set of select lists, checkboxes that have similar properties. I have them under the indexed_property. I was able to select the values from the select_list without any problem. However, when I use the check_myindexpropitem.mycheckbox, I get an error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `check_myindexpropitem' for #<myPage:0x3393588>.
```

I get a true returned for check_myindexpropitem.mycheckbox_element.enabled?

Page object code:

```
indexed_property(:myindexpropitem,
  [
    [:select_list, :myselectlist, {:id => 'drpV%sselect1'}],
    [:checkbox, :mycheckbox, {:id => 'checkV%scheckone'}]
  ])
```

Script:

```
if myindexpropitem[i].mycheckbox_element.enabled?  # i is from the for loop
  check_myindexpropitem[i].mycheckbox
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `check_` is in the wrong spot.

Remember that `myindexpropitem` is the method that just returns the object that responds to `[]`. The method `check_mycheckbox` is what is defined for the indexed element that is returned by `myindexpropitem[i]`.

The script code should be:

```
if myindexpropitem[i].mycheckbox_element.enabled?  # i is from the for loop
  myindexpropitem[i].check_mycheckbox
end
```